# Transient attribute in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

transient attribute dose not change , when update dependencies attribute in view object such as  salary  and (salary + 500) is  transient attribute  , when change salary  transient attribute don't update in (ADF)

Answer (score 1):

Set the attribute **updatable**=**Always** instead of **Never**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See answer at https://community.oracle.com/thread/4034828

And you should give more information about your environment (like JDev version) here too.

Comment: this is my question in this site !!

Comment: So, the answer is still over at the OTN space. And I still don't see any specific info about your environment here!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set four things right :

1. Salary attribute should have AutoSubmit set to true.
2. Transient attribute which consumes the Salary attribute should have Updatable as true.
3. Transient attribute to have Passivate as true (if your transient attribute is not in the same page. If you don't passivate, you may lose your calculated value while navigation.)
4. Even if the transient attribute get set, it will not reflect in UI, if you dont refresh the component in UI . Add a partial trigger on the transient attribute(target component) to listen to the Salary attribute(trigger component).